# android fragment Override onCreateAnimation

Tags: android, animation, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I use setCustomAnimations in a fragment (through FragmentTransaction) and for accomplish animation listeners override onCreateAnimation of the fragment. However, transit and nextAnim parameters always are 0!

```
@Override
public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {

}
```